# How to create stack bar chart in kendo ui angular

Tags: json, angular, kendo-ui-angular2, kendo-chart

I'm new to angular and I'm trying to create stack bar charts using kendo UI. I'm getting normal bar rather than stack bar chart, used `stack="true"` also not getting the view in stack.

Here is my code :

**app.component.html**

```
<kendo-chart style="height: 150px;">
    <kendo-chart-legend position="bottom" orientation="horizontal" [visible]="true"></kendo-chart-legend>

    <kendo-chart-area background="#F2FAFD"></kendo-chart-area>

    <kendo-chart-series>
        <kendo-chart-series-item type="column" *ngFor="let item of currentFindingsData" [data]="item.items" [name]="item.value" [stack]="true">

        </kendo-chart-series-item>
    </kendo-chart-series>
</kendo-chart>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
public currentFindingsJson: GroupResult[] = [{
    Value: "3"
    color: "#2E75B5"
    status: "CAT2 (Minor)"    
}, {
    Value: "10"
    color: "#2E75B5"
    status: "CAT1 (Minor)"
}];

this.currentFindingsData = groupBy(currentFindingsJson, [{field: 'status'}]) as GroupResult[];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify `[stack]="{ type: '100%' }"`.

Check this document link - https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/charts/series-types/bar/#toc-100-stacked-bar